# How do I convert an EWS change key to a Graph change key?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices

I want to convert a EWS managed API change key to the change key the Graph API returns for the same calendar event.

The EWS change key (obtained with [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/getitem-operation-calendar-item)) is

```
<t:ItemId ChangeKey="DwAAABYAAAB19EH4lfKlQYvApCHA0Dr0AABILgj3"/>
```

but the Graph change key (obtained with [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)) is vastly different:

```
"changeKey": "dfRB+JXypUGLwKQhwNA69AAASC4I9w=="
```

The [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0) about Graph calendar events indicates that they serve the same purpose, but it does not mention how to convert between the two nor why are the formats so different.

How do I convert between these two? I can't use any C# or powershell libraries, and I'd like to avoid sending additional APIs if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the translateExchangeIds API.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/translateExchangeIds

{
  "InputIds": ["DwAAABYAAAB19EH4lfKlQYvApCHA0Dr0AABILgj3"],
  "TargetIdType": "restId",
  "SourceIdType": "ewsId"
}
```

The response will have this shape:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.convertIdResult)",
    "value": [
        {
            "sourceId": "AAMkADEzOTExYjJkLTYxZDAAb18KkFAAA=",
            "targetId": "AAMkADEzOTExoeGgGqm4QrAAb18KkFAAA="
        }
    ]
}
```

The potential **TargetIdType** and **SourceIdType** values are:

```
 <EnumType Name="exchangeIdFormat">
    <Member Name="entryId" Value="0" />
    <Member Name="ewsId" Value="1" />
    <Member Name="immutableEntryId" Value="2" />
    <Member Name="restId" Value="3" />
    <Member Name="restImmutableEntryId" Value="4" />
  </EnumType>
```

This will be available in the next update of the [client libraries](https://github.com/microsoftgraph?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=sdk&type=&language=).

**update**

Once you have a converted item identifier, you can request the item and select the changekey property. It would make sense to do this in batches.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/messages/{messageid}/?$select=changekey
```

Comment: Trying this gave me this error: "[IdConverter::IsPublicFolder] Invalid compression id". Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That's odd. I can't tell whether it is your request or the service. Can you share the response body?

Comment: That request looks good. Is the calendar event a recurring meeting or a single appointment?  Can you try the convertId on another item type, like an email, and share the result?

Comment: I tried the change keys for a. a single-instance event b. a recurring event c. an email message, but all of them resulted in the same error as above

Comment: Going back to the pastebin example... That makes it sound like that it an identifier of an item that cannot be converted. Is the event in a public folder?

Comment: It's in a group calendar, and I'm not sure if a group calendar is in a public folder.

Comment: I see that you are making the call in the context of Me (your mailbox). Groups have their own mailbox. ConvertId is not supported cross mailbox. I think that is why this doesn't work.

Comment: I just tried converting the change keys of a message and an event in my user inbox, and it still doesn't work. Perhaps the API doesn't support converting change keys?

Comment: You'll need to convert the item id, and then request the change key using the convert item id. I'll update the answer with this information.

Comment: @MichaelMainer you mentioned that we can get the ChangeKey for a message. In EWS also each folder has ChangeKey but I am not able to get the ChangeKey of a folder in the same way of message. Do you know how can I get the ChangeKey of a folder in GraphAPI?